# Should I remove the OnInit implementation which is generated when a component is created by the Angular CLI if it isn't strictly necessary?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, conventions

My team is working on an Angular project and are trying to establish team code style conventions. A teammate has encouraged me to remove the `OnInit` implementation which was generated when I created the component using [Angular CLI](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component-command).

My teammate's argument in favor of removing the `OnInit` implementation is that this is unnecessary code and that failure to remove unused code may lead to misunderstanding by other developers who fail to recognize the implementation is unnecessary. This argument seems reasonable to me in general, but the idea of removing some generated code makes me somewhat uncomfortable.

I was curious if others in the Angular community have considered this type of coding convention and what factors led to a decision. Have you asked teammates to remove generated code which isn't strictly necessary? Would you consider this an unreasonable convention?

Comment: If you don’t need it, remove it.

Comment: @MikeOne I guess one aspect of this I failed to mention explicitly is that I'm trying to choose my battles and avoiding having code conventions that seem nit-picky or otherwise burdensome to the team. I take it you feel it is reasonable to ask one's teammates to remove this generated implementation? Thank you for your input

Comment: Whatever code inside `OnInit` will run when a component is being initialized. Now, do you want the component to do something when it happen?

Comment: The "schema" angular-cli use generate a empty function ngOnInit because most component use this function to initialize the component. But "most components" not main "all components", so as Mike say: "if you don't need it, remove it". e.g. when you generate a new Angular projects in stackblitz, it generate a hello.component. If you don't use, you remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So really there is no correct answer, it's for you and your team to decide on such conventions. I prefer to remove empty functions for the same reason as removing blocks of commented-out code; it just takes up space and distracts from the code that matters.

It's not a big deal either way but static code analysis tools such as SonarQube would pick this up as a code smell (see https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1186).